# Invalid Header Signature on Unix

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a program that works fine when run in Eclipse on a Windows box opening an Excel file, inserting a bunch of data, writing out the file, and attaching it to an email. However, when I copy the Excel files and JAR file with my code to our Unix test environment, I get the `Invalid header signature;` error.

I have ensured that the FTP is using a binary transfer, but the problem persists. The relevant code is:

```
InputStream excelStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(templateName);
if (excelStream != null) {
    LOG.debug(templateName + " has been found");
}
result = new HSSFWorkbook(excelStream);
excelStream.close();
```

The error happens on the `new HSSFWorkbook(excelStream)` call.

As I said, this code works locally. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work on the windows machine if you transfer the excel file back from the unix machine?

Comment: As it turned out, the problem was two-fold. There was a class path issue so the template wasn't being retrieved from where I thought it should be. And the file that WAS being retrieved was currupt (while the one I THOUGHT it was getting was not).